# Will a solidifying core inside a planet affect its appearance?

Tags: planet

In [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19406/has-the-iron-core-of-mars-really-solidified) question it is said that Mars once had a liquid core that solidified. If the liquid has a smaller density than the solid, will this affect the outer parts of the planets? For example, if the Earth's inner core (a part of which consists of iron and nickel) would solidify, would this give rise to a higher rotation speed or gargantuan Earthquakes? Would it have been visible on Mars?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Earth's inner core is solid. It's outer core is liquid. Lower density will always farther away from the planets center than high density, via gravitational differentiation or gravitational settling. What is appearance for you? The planetary radius? Surface roughness? Volcanic features?